# checkbox example android resource compilation failed

Tags: android, android-xml, xml-drawable

I have tried to rebuild this app: https://www.mkyong.com/android/android-checkbox-example/ but when I try to run it I got the failure: Android resource compilation failed C:\android Kurs programme\checkbox\app\src\main\res\drawable-v24\ic_launcher_foreground.xml:1: error: not well-formed (invalid token).

I have just tried to open a new project ( hello world that creates automatically during the start). But there is also the same failure , while running taskis in build.

Android resource compilation failed
C:\android kurs programme\MyApplication11\app\src\main\res\drawable-v24\ic_launcher_foreground.xml:1: error: not well-formed (invalid token).

Comment: Post your `drawable-v24\ic_launcher_foreground.xml` file, please

Answer (score 0):

> It is also just red underlined at the first line: package com.mkyong.android; and shows that. Package name 'com.mkyong.android' does not correspond to the file path 'com.example.checkbox'

Your folders structure should correspond to the used package name. So, you should either

1) rename your `mkyong` folder to `example` and `android` to `checkbox` if  you want to keep package name `com.mkyong.android`

OR

2) change package to `com.example.checkbox` in the first line of the source code file if you want to keep folders structure

**UPDATE**

To fix problem with Gradle, try add lines to your top-level `build.gradle` file:

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
    google()
}
```

As well, update **Gradle Plugin** and change **Gradle** version at line `distributionUrl` in file `gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties`

Comment: Thanks. no the first line is not red underlined anymore, But the failure is still there : Android resource compilation failed
C:\android kurs programme\checkbox2\app\src\main\res\drawable-v24\ic_launcher_foreground.xml:1: error: not well-formed (invalid token). My XML file is in res/layout.main.xml. the other one in res/values/strings.xml. While the  java file is at java/com.example.checkbox/MyAndroidAppActivity

Comment: "not well-formed" means your XML file has a structural error. Provide the `res\drawable-v24\ic_launcher_foreground.xml` XML file

Comment: File content looks very strange... Is `ic_launcher_foreground` drawable used in other resources anywhere?

Comment: Try following option: delete the file and entire `drawable-v24` folder if `ic_launcher_foreground.xml` is the only file in the folder; then rebuild the project

Comment: well there are two files in drawable. One is ic_launcher-background.xml and the other is ic_launcher_foreground.xml(v24). If i delete drawable, there will be this failure: see at the question

Comment: Last try i just copy and pasted the codes in its folders, because i had some problems with importing the android file. Now i tried to import the project. But now it could not find gradle 3.3.1. the failure is now in the question

Comment: @TommySupertramp, I have updated answer to suggest Gradle fix

Comment: I have just recognized, that the faulure happens even if i start a new empty project (hello world from start). So I think maybe there is suddenly a problem with gradle? The changes have not not helped yet.

Comment: Try to **File -> Invalidate Cache and Restart** in Android Studio